# Slope limit on player movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I use Unity3D and I have a player with a rigidbody. I add force tto the body for moving the player. My player walks over a terrain but is able to walk up mountains that are to steep to climb. I want to limit the player so it cannot walk up a slope that is to steep.

I know there is a CharacterController component that has this functionality, but I have to use the rigidbody, so I want the same but on my rigidbody.

I can get the normal of the triangle I am standing on, and calculate its angle, but I cannot seem to make the player stop moving up the slope. Only make the player stop moving (which makes the player unmovable once it hits a angled slope)

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: One naive, but simple, way would be to store your last position.  When your player enters a triangle whose slope is greater than your threshold, disable player controls and LERP back to last position then reenable control.

Comment: It is a fast paced game, so it is not really wanted that I disable the players controls, even if it is just for a few milliseconds. And then you cannot walk down a slope, because you will get send back to the top.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer without more details on how you're using the physics engine.  How/Are you using friction?  What angle are you applying the force?  Is it always horizontal or at the angle of the floor?  Does the player have a mass?

Anyway I can think of a few ways to solve this

1. Go the pure physics route.  Using player mass, friction, force angle, gravity, etc.  Get the physics to handle these situation for you.  This may take a fair amount of time and programming.
2. Keep the rigid body but fake the forces.  Scale the force you are applying to the body of the player with the angle of the triangle the player is on.  You can either use trigonometry to work out what you should apply or your own mapping.  By your own mapping I mean set an angle where 0 force is applied (say 45 degree) and do a linear(or non linear) scale on the force applied so on flat ground force is 1 and at 45 force is 0.
3. Don't use rigid bodies.  There is a reason most games don't use rigid bodies to control characters.  It's hard and complicated and most of the time not worth the time it would take.  Of course I don't know the details of your project so if this isn't an option, fine.

Hope that gives you some things to think about.

Comment: Thanks it most certainly gives me things to think about. Already got some code working but it is still pretty jittery. But I got switched to another assignment, so this will go on hold for now. Thanks for your insights!